# 'illegal start of expression' but outside of main

Tags: java

Please bear with me I'm very new to this. I am going through some tutorials and I am getting this error

```
GradeAnalyzer.java:51: error: illegal start of expression
myAnalyzer.getAverage(ArrayList<Integer>);
```

I have found so many threads saying take the method outside the main, however unless I am really stupid I'm pretty sure mine is outside of the main already. All advice regarding the matter is welcome (also feel free to heavily criticise the rest of my code).
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class GradeAnalyzer {

    public GradeAnalyzer() {

    }

    public int getAverage(ArrayList<Integer> grades) {

        ;
        if (grades.size() < 1) {

            System.out.println("Unfortunately the Array you are using is empty");

            return 0;

        } else {

            int sum = 0;

            for (Integer grade: grades) {
                System.out.println(grade);

                sum = sum + grade;
            }

            int average = sum / grades.size();
            System.out.println("Average =" + average);

            return average;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myClassroom.add(98);
        myClassroom.add(92);
        myClassroom.add(88);
        myClassroom.add(75);
        myClassroom.add(61);
        myClassroom.add(89);
        myClassroom.add(95);

    }

    public int myAnalyzer(ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom) {

        GradeAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new GradeAnalyzer();

        myAnalyzer.getAverage(ArrayList<Integer>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1 would be formatting the code with reasonable, consistent indentation. *(Edit: I've fixed it for you on this occasion.)*

Comment: Get rid of the colon after getAverage declaration. Since you're new, two tips: 1) format your code properly, 2) don't declare a variable of type `ArrayList`, use `List` (i.e. `List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: Indentation noted and thanks for editing it for me. This is where the site I'm learning from has possibly got me using bad habits, rather than teaching the more succinct ways of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the culprit:

```
myAnalyzer.getAverage(ArrayList<Integer>);
```

You've provided a *type* where an *expression* is expected. You probably wanted to pass in the `myClassroom` argument:

```
myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
```

---

Other notes:

- You probably want to get rid of the stray `;` at the top of `getAverage` as well. I don't think it's a syntax error, but it's pointless.
- I don't see a *call* to `myAnalyzer` (the method) anywhere.
- `myAnalyzer` is a very strange name for a method.
- It's best not to declare a local variable (`myAnalyzer`) inside a method with the same name (`myAnalyzer`) (although it's valid).
- In general, try to keep variable types to interfaces rather than concrete types, so:

  ```
  List<Integer> myClassroom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ```

  ...rather than using `ArrayList<Integer>` on the variable declaration.
- If using `ArrayList` (which does, after all, allocate and maintain an array), where possible tell it the initial capacity to use so you ensure that you're not doing unnecessary array re-allocations as you add things.
- `sum += grade;` is the idiomatic way to write `sum = sum + grade;` (although the latter works).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The site I'm using to learn sets out the scenarios, including the method names etc. The List<Integer> and the Sum+= are especially useful and good to know.

Answer (score 2):

```
myAnalyzer.getAverage(ArrayList<Integer>);
```

is not a valid method call. You should pass an instance whose type is `ArrayList<Integer>`.

For example, if you call it from your `main`, you can write :

```
myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
```

Or, if you don't want to put this method in your `main`, move the `myClassroom` `ArrayList` declaration and initialization to `myAnalyzer` method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. hopefully I can avoid bad habits with the help of this site.